# Page.Title equivalent in PHP

Tags: php, page-title

I want to change the title of my PHP pages dynamically but since the headers and footer sections are include files so I cannot use `<title><?php echo $title;?></title>` kind of solution.

I am wondering if there is any solution such as the one in Asp.NET `Page.Title = "Some Title";` maybe like `$page->set_title('Programmers Palace');`

Many thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Since the headers and footer sections are include files so I cannot use `<title><?php echo $title;?></title>` kind of solution.

You can. Just because the files are included doesn't mean you can't echo things there.

If you had a `Page` object...

#### index.php

```
<?php

$page = new Page('Programmers\' Palace');

include 'includes/header.php';
```

#### includes/header.php

```
<head>
  <title><?php echo $page->getTitle(); ?></title>
</head>
```

Comment: @Braveyard: `$title = "Foo"; include "header.php";`, then `$title == "Foo"` in header.php

Comment: @Boldewyn: According to your solutions, if there are many pages, then I should check all of them which seems not feasible.

Comment: Exactly as alex said, you can use this. Just for the further explanation - in php, any included files are treated like a part of original file.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$title = 'My Page';

include 'header.php';
```

then in header.php:

```
<title><?php echo $title;?></title>
```

This works because file includes in php are treated as if they are "pasted in between there".